# Transformar un JSONArray en un Array<Objeto>

Tags: android, json, api

Mi problema es el siguiente, yo traigo un `json` desde mi `api`, el mismo lo paso a un `JSONArray` el tema esta es q yo quiero armar un `Array<Especialidad>` y no se como hacerlo.

Especialidad_connect

```
public class Especialidad_connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    public String url = "http://192.168.1.55:8080/especialidad/";
    public JSONArray jArray;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            getJSON(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public JSONArray getJSON(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        return jArray;
    }
```

Quiero llevar esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el `json` que traigo desde mi `api` es `[{"idEspecialidad":"1","nombre":"clinico"},{"idEspecialidad":"2","nombre":"pediatra"}]`

Especialidad

```
public class Especialidad {
    long id;
    String nombre;

    public Especialidad(long idEspecialidad, String nombre) {
        this.id = idEspecialidad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Especialidad() {

    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Germanccho ya creaste tu objeto Especialidad? agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Veo que usas clases de "Apache", son obsoletas, deberías cambiar a HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: @Jorgesys ahi te agregue la clase especialidad, como quedaria utilizando `HttpUrlConnection`

Comment: Gracias @Germanccho solo tienes que crear una lista de objetos Especialidad y obtener los valores de los objetos en el JSONArray que obtienes. Agregué también un ejemplo de como usar la clase HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al tener tu JSONArray puedes obtener los valores mediante un bucle y agregarlos a una instancia de `Especialidad` y cada instancia a una lista de especialidad.

Crea una lista:

```
 List<Especialidad> listadoEspecialidades = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();
```

y obtén los valores de cada `JSONObject` en el `JSONArray` y agregalis a un objeto y posteriormente a la lista:

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    especialidad = new Especialidad();
    especialidad.setId(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idEspecialidad"));
    especialidad.setNombre(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
    listadoEspecialidades.add(especialidad);
}
```

---

Este sería el código:

```
 jArray = getJSON(url);

 List<Especialidad> listadoEspecialidades = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();
                Especialidad especialidad;

 for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     especialidad = new Especialidad();
     especialidad.setId(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idEspecialidad"));
     especialidad.setNombre(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
     listadoEspecialidades.add(especialidad);
 }
```

---

**Importante**: Recuerda que las clases "Apache" para conexión son obsoletas en Android, debes usar [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
 public JSONArray getJSON(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";


        /*HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();*/

            try {
                URL urlConn = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn.openConnection();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e("Error !", ex.getMessage());
            }





        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        return jArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero cambia la asignatura de la clase AsyncTask modificando el tercer tipo de dato generico a `ArrayList<Especialidad>` :

```
public class Especialidad_connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Especialidad>> {
```

Esto modifica  también la asignatura del metodo `doInBackground` a la siguiente:

```
  protected ArrayList<Especialidad> doInBackground(String... strings) {
```

Esto para retornar el array de especialidades desde el metodo `doInBackground`.

Ahora para convertir el `JSONArray` que retorna el metodo `getJSON()`, solo tienes que  recorrerlo utilizando un `for`:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<Especialidad> doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = getJSON(url);

        ArrayList<Especialidad> especialdades = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();


        for(int i = 0, total = jArray.length();i<total;i++)
        {
        // obtenemos el JSONObject del indice i
          JSONObject especialidadJSON = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
          Especialidad especialidad = new Especialidad();

          // le asignamos los valores del json a la especialidad
          especialidad.setId(especialidadJSON.getInt("idEspecialidad"));
          especialidad.setNombre(especialidadJSON.getString("nombre");

          // lo agregamos la coleccion
          especialdades.add(especialdiad);
        }

        return especialdades;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Nota como se utiliza el metodo [`getJSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject(int)) sobre el `JSONArray`, esto poder obtener el objeto json del indice especificado y poder acceder a sus propiedades.

Este seria el codigo completo:

```
public class Especialidad_connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Especialidad>> {

    public String url = "http://192.168.1.55:8080/especialidad/";
    public JSONArray jArray;


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Especialidad> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = getJSON(url);

            ArrayList<Especialidad> especialdades = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();


            for(int i = 0, total = jArray.length();i<total;i++)
            {
            // obtenemos el JSONObject del indice i
              JSONObject especialidadJSON = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
              Especialidad especialidad = new Especialidad();

              // le asignamos los valores del json a la especialidad
              especialidad.setId(especialidadJSON.getInt("id"));
              especialidad.setNombre(especialidadJSON.getString("nombre");

              // lo agregamos la coleccion
              especialdades.add(especialdiad);
            }

            return especialdades;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public JSONArray getJSON(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        return jArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecuted(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades)
    {
        // aqui manejas las especialidades retornadas
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma más corta usando la biblioteca Jackson seria:

```
String jsonString = "....";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Especialidad[] arr = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Especialidad[].class);
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/blob/master/README.md